# Using OnDelete with a Reversed() Array - IndexSet does not match

Tags: swiftui

I would like to display an array in reverse order so the last item to be added to the array appears first and then use the OnDelete function to remove items. The issue is the display index value no longer matches the array order, the code below works but I expect there will be something simpler. The code below will only work(if uncommented) for a single line delete, which is fine for my application but I'm assuming there is a more appropriate solution that I'm missing.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var testArray = ["Element 1", "Element 2","Element 3", "Element 4","Element 5", "Element 6" ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            
            List{
                ForEach (testArray.reversed(), id: \.self){item in
                    
                    Text("\(item)")
                    
                }.onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet){
        
        //This will not work if .reversed() is used in the ForEach.
        testArray.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        
        //This Code Works for single line deleting, but no doubt there is smarter way...?
//        var offsetValue:Int = 0
//        let arraySize = testArray.count - 1
//        for offset in offsets {
//            offsetValue = offset
//                   }
//        testArray.remove(at: (arraySize - offsetValue))
   
    }    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to change original array, like

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var testArray = [
                          "Element 1", "Element 2","Element 3", 
                          "Element 4","Element 5", "Element 6"
                       ].reversed()                           // << here !!
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List{
                ForEach (testArray, id: \.self){item in
                    Text("\(item)")
                }.onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet){
        testArray.remove(atOffsets: offsets)   // now this works !!
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a really helpful suggestion and I will see if it can work for my project. The array I'm using in the full code is from Core Data, therefore this solution may need a little more testing. Also, I have a 'Add New Item' button and with this method the new items are added to the bottom of the List view and I need them at the top.